# TFS not showing any data in sprint (iteration) burndown chart

Tags: tfs

When I go to my dashboard in TFS (2018) and add a burndown chart widget, the chart contains no data. Is there something I'm missing? The sprint contains resolved/closed backlog items. Thank you

For reference:

[image: For reference]

Answer (score 1):

Have you [Set the team **capacity** and **activity**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/capacity-planning?view=vsts#set-team-capacity-and-activity)?

Seems you didn't set the team **capacity** and **activity** correctly. Also you need to specify the **Activity** and **Effort**, **Remaining Work** for each related work items.  See [Capacity planning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/capacity-planning?view=vsts) and [Sprint planning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scrum/sprint-planning?view=vsts) for details.

A burndown chart only applies to a sprint that's in progress, and the chart should start from the first working day (Spend time on tasks/bugs etc).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however in my TFS "User Stories" don't have Activity, Effort or Remaining Work (but they have "Story Points" instead of "Effort". However, "Bugs" have "remaining" and "Activity" fields but not effort (it's called story points for me). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ryan In sprint (iteration), it's more concerned about the `Tasks` and `Bugs`. The fields may different due to the template you used. Whatever, you need to set the `Original Estimate` work (hours) then set the `Remaining` and `Completed`. Thus the system can identify how the Sprint (iteration) goes and show the progress in burndown chart. So, just have a try for that.

Comment: Right now we aren't estimating by hours, just assigning story points. Is there no way to generate a burn down chart without putting in estimates for hours?

Comment: @Ryan No, we have to set the `Original Estimate` work, otherwise the  burn down chart will not work without estimate work hours and real time spending recorded. Actually the burn down chart displays how the project goes in progress.